# Supress page numbers for \part in toc

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, parts

I have created two custom macros for chapter and part command. When I am using following code:

```
\documentclass[final]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\mdseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\mdseries}

\long\def \mychapter#1{
\chapter*{#1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
}

\long\def \mypart#1#2{
\part*{#1 \\* #2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1\\ #2}
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\mypart{PART NUMBER 1}{Part Title}
\mychapter{Some chapter 1}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mychapter{Some chapter 2}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mychapter{Some chapter 3}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mypart{PART NUMBER 2}{Part Title}
\mychapter{Some chapter 4}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mychapter{Some chapter 5}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mychapter{Some chapter 6}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mychapter{Some chapter 7}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mypart{PART NUMBER 3}{Part Title}
\mychapter{Some chapter 8}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mychapter{Some chapter 9}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mychapter{Some chapter 10}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mychapter{Some chapter 11}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

it generates following Table of Contents:

[image: Table of Contents with improper page numbers]

Page numbers for `\part` in this Table of Contents are not correct. Instead of pointing to real page where `\part` text is printed, they point to page where first chapter within that part starts.

I have used `pdflatex` two times to make sure page numbers will be correct, but they are not.

**Questions**:

1. Why are page numbers for `\part` not correct in ToC?
2. How can I supress page numbers for `\part` altogether in ToC, but leave Table of Contents entry for `\part` unchanged otherwise?

Comment: 1. Probably because \part is on a single page of its own, and the real contents begins with the first chapter. So it's rather sensible. 2. I only know how to do that with `titletoc`.

Comment: @Bernard Can you post an answer with solution to 2. with ``titletoc``?

Comment: You should clear the double pages before a new part starts: `\cleardoublepage`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Why?

Comment: @Rafal: I suspect a side effect of `tocloft`. The page information is not updated correctly otherwise.

Comment: @Rafal: Why do you redefine `\part` at all?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I did so long time ago and never thought about it again. But I guess that for 2 reasons: 1) I didn't want to write ``\part*{}`` each time to avoid part numbers in TOC (somehow, ``\mypart{}`` is easier to use for me), 2) Because I needed to add ``\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1\\ #2}`` and didn't want to type it by hand each time when it could be handled by macro.

Comment: @Rafal: I still wonder a little bit about that 2 arguments of your `\mypart` command.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Those entries with ``\mypart`` have two elements - usually something like "PART ONE" and second element - "Some Title" so I need 2 arguments to properly typeset it in ToC and in actual text. If that is not correct reasoning, then please let me know - maybe I am missing something obvious.

Comment: If `PART ONE` is equivalent to `PART 1`, i.e. real numbers and not their words (1-> ONE, 2->TWO,etc.) this could probably done automatically by changing the format of `\thepage`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I specifically want to avoid automated number of items in ToC and my solution seems easy to use (at least for me), so I don't see anything wrong with it (even though there are other ways to do it).

Comment: @Rafal: Nevertheless I was thrilled by providing such automatic solution. Just for fun and for completness ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for suggestion. Each time I ask question on TeX SE I not only get answer, but I also learn that my code could be written better, which is always good to know even if I stubbornly stick with my original code :)

Comment: @Rafal: We all learn, that's the fun about TeX.SE!!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're taking the wrong approach. If you don't want any element to be numbered, just tell LaTeX so.

```
\documentclass[final]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\mdseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\mdseries}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}

\newcommand\mypart[2]{\part{#1 \\ #2}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\mypart{PART NUMBER 1}{Part Title}
\chapter{Some chapter 1}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Some chapter 2}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Some chapter 3}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mypart{PART NUMBER 2}{Part Title}
\chapter{Some chapter 4}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Some chapter 5}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Some chapter 6}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Some chapter 7}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mypart{PART NUMBER 3}{Part Title}
\chapter{Some chapter 8}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Some chapter 9}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Some chapter 10}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Some chapter 11}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

LaTeX will take care of the rest.

[image]

If you want to suppress the page number for the parts, then do like this:

```
\documentclass[final]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\mdseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\mdseries}

% suppress page number in toc for parts
\cftpagenumbersoff{part}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}

\newcommand\mypart[2]{\part{#1 \\ #2}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\mypart{PART NUMBER 1}{Part Title}
\chapter{Some chapter 1}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Some chapter 2}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Some chapter 3}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mypart{PART NUMBER 2}{Part Title}
\chapter{Some chapter 4}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Some chapter 5}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Some chapter 6}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Some chapter 7}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mypart{PART NUMBER 3}{Part Title}
\chapter{Some chapter 8}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Some chapter 9}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Some chapter 10}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Some chapter 11}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks to Mico for suggesting `\cftpagenumbersoff`.

Comment: Both code snippets work great. One question though - what do you mean by "If you don't want any element to be numbered, just tell LaTeX so"? Do you refer to ``\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}`` command?

Comment: @Rafal Yes, that's the proper way, rather than defining a `\mychapter` command.

Comment: Why is this more 'proper' than defining new command?

Comment: @Could one not say `\begingroup \renewcommand{\thepage}{} \part{#1}{#2} \endgroup` inside of your `\mypart` definition in order to drop the visual page numbering?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer No.

Comment: @Rafal For one thing: this doesn't require `\addcontentsline`.

Answer (score 3):

This addresses the wrong page numbers first, but is only a hack due to the somewhat 'unhealthy' definition of `\mypart`

```
\documentclass[final]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\mdseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\mdseries}

\long\def \mychapter#1{
\chapter*{#1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
}


\long\def \mypart#1#2{%
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1\\ #2}
\part*{#1 \\* #2}

}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\mypart{PART NUMBER 1}{Part Title}
\mychapter{Some chapter 1}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mychapter{Some chapter 2}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mychapter{Some chapter 3}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mypart{PART NUMBER 2}{Part Title}
\mychapter{Some chapter 4}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mychapter{Some chapter 5}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mychapter{Some chapter 6}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mychapter{Some chapter 7}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mypart{PART NUMBER 3}{Part Title}
\mychapter{Some chapter 8}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mychapter{Some chapter 9}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mychapter{Some chapter 10}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mychapter{Some chapter 11}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT** Redefining the `\mypart` command.

I used the suggestions of egreg and mico and suggest another `\mypart` command which removes the first argument. I do **not** expect, that my answer is accepted.

```
\documentclass[final]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\mdseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\mdseries}

\cftpagenumbersoff{part} % According to Mico's suggestion

% 'Unhealthy' chapter redefinition 
\long\def \mychapter#1{
\chapter*{#1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
}%

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}%  % According to egreg's suggestion

% If literal number words should be used: apply this one 
\renewcommand{\thepart}{PART NUMBER~\NUMBERstring{part}}%
% If really numbers are desired:
%\renewcommand{\thepart}{PART NUMBER~\arabic{part}}

\newcommand{\mypart}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{part}% cheap trick ;-)
\part{\thepart~ \\* #1}
}%


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\mypart{Part Title}

\mychapter{Some chapter 1}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mychapter{Some chapter 2}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mychapter{Some chapter 3}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mypart{Part Title}
\mychapter{Some chapter 4}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mychapter{Some chapter 5}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mychapter{Some chapter 6}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mychapter{Some chapter 7}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mypart{Part Title}
\mychapter{Some chapter 8}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mychapter{Some chapter 9}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mychapter{Some chapter 10}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mychapter{Some chapter 11}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Weirdly, it works only if ``\addcontentsline`` is before ``\part`` line. Otherwise, page numbers are again incorrect. Do you have any idea how to supress page numbers altogether?

Comment: @Rafal - Where do you want to suppress the page numbers for part pages: In the ToC, the actual pages that contain the part headers, or both?

Comment: @Mico I want to supress page numbers in the ToC. Actually I supressed them on the actual pages as well, so here I just need to supress them in ToC.

Comment: @Rafal - To suppress the showing of page numbers for part-level entries in the ToC, issue the command `\cftpagenumbersoff{part}`. (See also p. 12 of the user guide of the `tocloft` package...)

Comment: @Mico That is actually most straightforward way of doing it, since I use ``tocloft`` package already. Thanks!